# Unet input and output

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I am totally new to computer vision, and am trying to train a model that takes an normal 3 channel image (RGB) and gives an output, which is just a simple binary mask. From my best knowledge, architecture called Unet does something like this. For example, TernausnetV2 worked quite well in a kaggle competition. In this kind of model architecture, is the input and output I'm thinking of correct ?

I have 3 channel image (RGB) and the binary masked image (which is same size as the 3 channel image, and all the values are 1 or 0).
Thanks for the help in prior.

Answer (score 0):

The computer vision task you are talking about is called a semantic segmentation and the U-Net model is a basic autoencoder architecture used for a similar problem. There are many models nowadays derived from the U-Net (Ternausnet is one of them), some comparison can be found in the Papers with code SOTA comparison [link](https://paperswithcode.com/task/semantic-segmentation).
U-Net architecture usually uses 3 channel input size for RGB image processing and 1 channel output size - models usually use as a final layer a sigmoid activation convolution layer with core size 1x1 which basically goes through the entire image and on every pixel computes sigmoid function 
- wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) which assignes every pixel a values between 0 and 1 (depending on the data magnitude you can use also tanh - -1/1). More information can be found in this awesome tutorial from Towards data science [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-semantic-segmentation-with-unet-6be4f42d4b47)

Comment: Great information, I'll keep those in mind. Thanks a lot.